# Difference between printing array returned from toarray() method using enhanced for loop and traditional for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, toarray

I  have  this  code,

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(1);
        al.add(2);
        al.add(3);
        Integer a[]=new Integer[2];
        al.toArray(a);
        for(int i:a)
        System.out.println(i);
        /*for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);*/

    }
}
```

The  above  code  throws  NullPointerException  but  if  I  try  to  take  the  commented  part  off,  and  comment enhanced  for  loop  it  will  print  null 2  times.  Printing  a.length  prints  2. Setting  Integer  array  size  to  3  will  print  123.

Now  correct  me  if  I  am  wrong:

1>  My  understanding  of  toArray(T[] a)  method  is,  if  the  size  of  the  array  is  less  than  elements  in  the  list,  new  array  will  be  created  with  size  specified  by  the  array  and  elements  in  it  will  be  null,  considering  this.  my  array  should  look  like  this        a[]={null,null};

2> Difference  between  enhanced  for  loop  and  traditional  for  loop  is  that  you  can't  modify  or  delete  the  individual  element  in  enhanced  for  loop.

But,  why  is  this  different  in  this  program?  I  am  just  printing  them,  why  is  enhanced  for  loop  not  printing  null  and  throwing  NullPointerException?

Comment: You need to use the return value of `toArray(a)`, not the passed in value.  Note in the documentation for "Parameters" where it says: "a - the array into which the elements of this collection are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose".  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T[]%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toArray(a)` method returns the converted array and that's what you should be using; it didn't use your array since it wasn't large enough.

That is,

1. if your list's size was `2` (the same as the length of the array you
   provided the method with) or
2. if your array length was `3` (the same
   as the size of the list you wanted to convert into an array),

you wouldn't have needed the returned array; and as such, your `for` loops would have printed what you wanted them to.

As for the `NullPointerException`, it's because of the autounboxing it does from `Integer` to `int`. That is, the following code wouldn't have thrown an `NPE`:

```
for(Integer i : a)
{
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

while the following code will (as it did in your case):

```
for(int i : a)
{
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

As to why the compiler does the unboxing with the above enhanced for loop, think about it - the contents of the array are `boxed` integers. You try to assign them to a `primitive` int reference (read it as *for every int in the array*), so the only way to do it is unbox the boxed object.

```
for(int i : a)
{
  System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

translates to

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println((int) a[i]);  // a[i] is null here, so casting causing an NPE
}
```

or even more correctly,

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println(a[i].intValue()); // a[i] is null here, causing an NPE
}
```

Comment: 1>  what is autounboxing?  I  am  aware of autoboxing and unboxing.
2>  Is  autounboxing  doesn't  happen  with  traditional  for  loop?
3> Another answer to this query  says my array a  will  be  of  size  3.  Am  I  wrong  in  understanding  toArray()  method?

Comment: By `autounboxing` I really meant the `unboxing` that `compiler` does on your behalf. The point 2> you made is exactly why I called it `autounboxing` - the compiler does it for you; you don't do it in the case you showed. And on 3> I meant that your array length should at least have been `3`, i.e `Integer[] a = new Integer[3]`.

Comment: Thanks  @mystarrocks  my  1st  and  2nd  points  are  clear.  my  3rd  point  was  based  on  toArray()  method  specification  in  JLS.  According  to  which  array  a  will  be  created  newly  as  size  of  collection  and  array  are  different  and  size  of  the  array  is  smaller  than  that  of  collection.  Is  this  new  array  will  be  of  size  specified  by  the  collection  or  specified  by  the  array?  i.e  in  my  program  a  will  be  of  size  3  or  2?

Comment: Another  answer  by  another  person  to  my  same  query  says  array  size  will  be  3.  But  no,  my  array  size  if  printed  says  its  2.

Comment: In your program, the size of `a` was and will ever be `2`, which is what the problem is. Its size should have been `3` to fit all the elements in your source collection, i.e the list. That is why the `.toArray` method is forced to create a new array of length `3` (to fit all your elements from the source list). 

To summarize, the length of `a` will be `2` and the length of the returned array from the `toArray` method will be `3`.

Comment: I  got  you  now.  Thank  you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

It takes array as parameter to copy all the elements and returns that array. If your array is large enough then it copy on that otherwise same new array at runtime is allocated for this purpose. In your case, a is of size 2. so new array a of size 3 is created runtime and values are copied to this new array and returned.

2nd thing you are printing a[i] instead of i. since i is containing element value so print i.

something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<>();
    al.add(1);
    al.add(2);
    al.add(3);
    Integer a[]=new Integer[2];
    a=al.toArray(a);
    for(Integer i:a) //or for(int i:a)
    System.out.println(i);
}
```